# How to use Bootstrap-Select "Core Options" with Javascript?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using the [Bootstrap-Select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) plugin on my simple HTML page and I am wanting to take advantage of some of the [Core Options](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/) to customize the selector more. I would like to use javascript as I am more familar with its syntax than JQuery, but I cant find any examples of how to use it. For example, to change the selects "non selected text" i tried this in a javascript function:

```
document.getElementById("teamsID").noneSelectedText = "No Teams Selected Yet";
```

but didnt get any luck. Could really use some help from some friendly neighborhood coders!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please explain in detail.

Comment: I am basically just trying to use javascript to make use of the bootstrap-select core options. I just didnt know how to syntactically do that

Answer (score 0):

It's a very old question.
But nobody given any answer, so...
You should pass the "core options" to the function selectpicker():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
      noneSelectedText: 'No Teams Selected Yet'
    });
});
```